# Как передать данные с одной страницы на другую во время перехода с нее по ссылке

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня есть web страница, при переходе по ссылке с которой, надо передать некоторые данные на страницу, на которую я перехожу. Как можно это осуществить? С сервером на js общение через websocket.

Comment: в url положить параметрами

Comment: А если информации достаточно много?

Comment: тогда можно её сложить в `localStorage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так например:

```html
<input id="query">
<a href="#" onclick='document.location.href="https://codepen.io/" + encodeURIComponent(query.value)'>go</a>
```

PS: если информации много, можно её сложить в `localStorage` и по ссылке передать этот ключ